# Loop column names in get_dummies for pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, loops

For pandas I have written the code below in order to convert all categorical features. However after I run it on my data set and check data types, nothing changes.

Thank you in advance.

Code:

```
def dummy_conv(data):
    names=data.select_dtypes(exclude=['number']).columns
    for c in names:
        data=pd.get_dummies(data,columns=[c],drop_first=True)

dummy_conv(data_train)

data_train.dtypes # object features are not converted
```

Answer (score 0):

Looping is not necessary, filter by list of columns, also not forget for `return`:

```
data_train = pd.DataFrame({'A':list('abcdef'),
                   'B':[4,5,4,5,5,4],
                   'C':[7,8,9,4,2,3],
                   'D':[1,3,5,7,1,0],
                   'E':[5,3,6,9,2,4],
                   'F':list('aaabbb')})

print (data_train)
   A  B  C  D  E  F
0  a  4  7  1  5  a
1  b  5  8  3  3  a
2  c  4  9  5  6  a
3  d  5  4  7  9  b
4  e  5  2  1  2  b
5  f  4  3  0  4  b

def dummy_conv(data):
    names=data.select_dtypes(exclude=['number']).columns

    return pd.get_dummies(data[names], drop_first=True)

df = dummy_conv(data_train)
print (df)
   A_b  A_c  A_d  A_e  A_f  F_b
0    0    0    0    0    0    0
1    1    0    0    0    0    0
2    0    1    0    0    0    0
3    0    0    1    0    0    1
4    0    0    0    1    0    1
5    0    0    0    0    1    1
```

If want convert only non numeric columns:

```
def dummy_conv(data):
    return pd.get_dummies(data,drop_first=True)
    #same output like
    #names=data.select_dtypes(exclude=['number']).columns
    #return pd.get_dummies(data,columns=names,drop_first=True)
df = dummy_conv(data_train)
print (df)
   B  C  D  E  A_b  A_c  A_d  A_e  A_f  F_b
0  4  7  1  5    0    0    0    0    0    0
1  5  8  3  3    1    0    0    0    0    0
2  4  9  5  6    0    1    0    0    0    0
3  5  4  7  9    0    0    1    0    0    1
4  5  2  1  2    0    0    0    1    0    1
5  4  3  0  4    0    0    0    0    1    1
```

Comment: Thank you very much. Works perfectly.